# FormCollection parameter is empty while using @Ajax.BeginForm and html5 controls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, ajaxhelper

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC5 project with boostrap, jquery, jquery UI. Submit is working fine but FormCollection in create Action is arriving empty in HomeController. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or is missing. PLease need help. Below snippet code.

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Empleado</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post" }, new { id = "dialog", name = "dialog" })) 
                {
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Nombres</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalNombres" placeholder="Nombres" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Apellidos</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalApellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalFechaNacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Tipo Documento</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="modalTipoDocumento">
                                    <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">--- Seleccione ---</option>
                                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TiposDocumento)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Descripcion</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Número de Documento</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalNumeroDocumento" placeholder="Número Documento" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGrabar">Grabar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HomeController is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        string nombres = collection["modalNombres"];
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of you `<input>` elements have `name` attributes so there is nothing sent to the server. Change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalNombres" placeholder="Nombres" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="modalNombres" placeholder="Nombres" />
```

There is no need for `id` attributes unless you using javascript/jquery to refer to them.

However, I very strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through some basic tutorials and learn how to generate a view in MVC. You should have a model, use the strongly typed html helpers to bind to the properties of your model, and the POST method should have a parameter for the model so it is bound (you should never use `FormCollection` in MVC)

Note also, you using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which uses ajax to post the form values  so `return RedirectToAction("Index");` in your POST method is pointless. Ajax calls stay on the same page, they do not redirect.